# Starting Selenium with Chrome on Linux headless adds many command line arguments, and some of them contradicting my manually added arguments

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chrome and chromedriver 119... versions, chromedriver was downloaded using selenium-manager to match exact chrome version.

Starting Selenium with Chrome on Linux headless adds many command line arguments. I completely OK with this, and do understand that many of them serves the purpose to allow controlling chrome with chromedriver, and are according to browser testing best practices.

However of them seems to be contradicting my manually added arguments. I examined the started google-chrome process command line here it is:

```
--headless=new (this is mine)
--disable-infobars (this is mine)
--hide-crash-restore-bubble (this is mine)
--noerrdialogs (this is mine)
--user-data-dir=/tmp/.chrome/opl01 (this is mine)
--window-size=1920,1080 (this is mine, I would like to have the desktop layout test use cases)
--start-maximized (mine, could be obsolete)
--remote-debugging-port=9231 (this is mine, I want deterministic port, because I am remote devtooling from an other machine, so must create SSH tunnel, random ports would be inconvenient)

--allow-pre-commit-input 
--disable-background-networking 
--disable-client-side-phishing-detection 
--disable-default-apps 
--disable-hang-monitor 
--disable-popup-blocking 
--disable-prompt-on-repost 
--disable-sync 
--enable-automation 
--enable-logging 
--log-level=0 
--no-first-run 
--no-service-autorun 
--password-store=basic 
--test-type=webdriver 
--use-mock-keychain 
--ozone-platform=headless 
--ozone-override-screen-size=800,600 
--use-angle=swiftshader-webgl data:
```

I am particularly worried about the two `ozon-...`. The `ozone-override-screen-size=800,600`  seems to be overriding my 1920x1080 intention. The `ozone-platform=headless` seems to be overring my intention, that I would like to use the **new** headless mode...

The exact same code on windows, using also the 119... pairs of chrome and chromedriver does not add automatically many of those arguments, especially not the `ozon...`

**Additional info:**

I am starting Selenium with the following C# code:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("headless=new");
options.AddArgument("window-size=1920,1080");

options.AddArgument("hide-crash-restore-bubble"); // This can help to disable the "Restore pages?" popup
options.AddArgument("disable-infobars"); // This can also help to disable other popups
options.AddArgument("noerrdialogs");
options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=mydir");
options.AddArgument("remote-debugging-port=9230");
var path = ""; // chromedriver is in the same folder as the executable  
var driver = new ChromeDriver(path, options);
```